# Constrained cell input in editable Shiny/DT only active once

Tags: r, shiny, dt

My Shiny app has the following functionality. Alongside a table consisting of a `reactiveValues`-nested reactive DT `allocation_engine()`, the user inputs an amount that is automatically allocated across a `DT` column ("Allocation") subject to some input constraints. This script works fine through the use of `reactiveValues`.

I am also implementing the ability to manually enter cells in the Allocation column by allowing the DT to be editable. These entries are subject to one constraint. **My script works in the sense that the constraint is active once, but not again**! Firstly, let me elaborate;

The user's manual input `DT$Allocation[i] <= DT$AIA[i]` must hold, where AIA simply is another column in the `DT` rendered from `reactiveValues`. Hence, if `DT$AIA = c(10,20)` then the maximum manual entry into `DT$Allocation[2]` is 20. If the user inputs 30, the actual implemented entry should thus be 20.

Bottom line: This restriction works, but only the first time that you cross the restriction! In the example above; If I enter `DT$Allocation[2] = 30` one time, the resulting entry is 20 owing to the restriction. The next time I enter 30 in the same cell, the restriction does not work and the cell enters as 30, whilst the DT does not seem to update.

I have followed Yihui's editable DT guide in order to implement this logic:
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28#issuecomment-236293247

Another SO question which relates to editing DT tables, for some background:
[R Shiny DT - edit values in table with reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470097/r-shiny-dt-edit-values-in-table-with-reactive)

My code follows below. Happy to provide more information if you feel that you can help me.

```
# Container for reactive values created here:
allocation_values = reactiveValues(rendered = NULL) 

observe({    
      rendered = allocation_engine()
      allocation_values$rendered = rendered 
})

# The reactiveValue container is rendered as an editable DT
output$alloc_table = DT::renderDataTable(  
      allocation_values$rendered, 
      server=TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
         options=list(pageLength=10, search = list(smart = TRUE)),
             selection = 'none',
             editable = TRUE                  
)

alloc_table_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('alloc_table')

observeEvent(input$alloc_table_cell_edit, { 
#When the user carries out a manual entry:

       info = input$alloc_table_cell_edit
       str(info)
       i = info$row
       j = info$col
       v = min(info$value, allocation_values$rendered$AIA[i])

       # ^ Create a value [v] that is the minimum of the entry and the
       # corresponding AIA of the same row as the entry

       if (j == 9) {  # If the input column is "Allocation"
                      # replace the selected row in Allocation with the 
                      # variable [v] calculated above     
           allocation_values$rendered$Allocation[i] = DT::coerceValue(v, 
           allocation_values$rendered$Allocation[i])

       # This step is actually unnecessary for my implementation, 
       # but included in Yihui's guide.
       replaceData(alloc_table_proxy, allocation_values$rendered, 
           resetPaging=TRUE, rownames=FALSE)                            
}}
```

Thanks, 
J.

Comment: A minimum reproducible example would help. Also you may want to look at rhandsontable