# Using reactiveValues to updateSelectInput in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I've been following the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470097/r-shiny-dt-edit-values-in-table-with-reactive) for creating an editable dataTable in R Shiny. Now I want to update the user's choices for another input, but the values are not updating in `pickerInput()`, as they correctly do in the `renderPrint()` function.

Can anyone enlighten me on the best way to use `updateSelectInput()` when trying to get objects stored within `reactiveValues()`? Thanks in advance.

````
library(DT)
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species)

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1'),
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "x2",
      label = "",
      choices =  unique(iris$Species)
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("print")
  ),

server <- function(input, output, session){
  x = reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  observe({
    x$df = iris
  })
  
  output$x1 = renderDT(
    x$df,
    rownames = F,
    editable = T)
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
  
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    info = input$x1_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1
    v = info$value
    x$df[i, j] <- isolate(DT::coerceValue(v, x$df[i, j]))
    updateSelectInput(session, "x2", choices = unique(x$df$Species)) #NOT BREAKING, BUT NOT WORKING
  })
  
  output$print <- renderPrint({
    unique(x$df$Species)
  })
}
)```
````

Comment: You have to use `updatePickerInput`, not `updateSelectInput`.